# Show markdowns for revision links

Tags: feature-request, markdown, revisions-list, diff

While seeing revisions of a post, there are three options inline, side-by-side and side-by-side markdown for every revision:

> [image: screenshot]

And every revision has link facility to share/link:

[image: screen]

But the revision page (site.se.com/revisions/post-id/no.of revision) that is opened by mentioned *`link` has no/missing options like inline, side-by-side or side-by-side.*

While sharing link of one revision, I found that user to which link is share will *not be able to know what is edited/revised at all*.

So, I think it is *better* to provide such options/feature i.e inline, side-by-side or side-by-side for *effective vision* of revision.

Comment: you could insta-close it yourself by clicking the "Yes, this solves my problem" button that appeared on top while there was pending close vote.